# enum type not available

Tags: c, enums, typedef, c99

I'm having problems with an enum type. I have the following in my header:

```
enum map_type_t{
    MAP_TYPE_PORT,
    MAP_TYPE_VLAN,
    MAP_TYPE_L2MAC,
    MAC_TYPE_VPWS,
    MAC_TYPE_BFD,
    MAC_TYPE_VPLS
};
```

I included the header in my `C` file and that's eherre I have a prototype like `int store_to_flash (map_type_t map_type, void* pData)` but now, for some reason, the type `map_type_t` isn't being recognized, why not I'm wondering? I've also tried to typedef the enum instead but couldn't get that working either, it looked like:

```
typedef enum {
    MAP_TYPE_PORT,
    MAP_TYPE_VLAN,
    MAP_TYPE_L2MAC,
    MAC_TYPE_VPWS,
    MAC_TYPE_BFD,
    MAC_TYPE_VPLS
}map_type_t;
```

What's the problem, I don't understand.

PS: this is with the `diab` compiler in `C99` mode

**edit 1**

interesting, if I move

```
typedef enum map_type_e {
    MAP_TYPE_PORT,
    MAP_TYPE_VLAN,
    MAP_TYPE_L2MAC,
    MAC_TYPE_VPWS,
    MAC_TYPE_BFD,
    MAC_TYPE_VPLS
}map_type_t;
```

from my header into the C file on the very top, after my `include`s it seems to work just fine... now that's odd isn't it? Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
enum map_type_t { /* ... */ };
```

creates a type named `enum map_type_t`. The identifier `map_type_t` is a tag, not a type name.

You can either use a `typedef` to create an alias for the type, or you can refer to it by its name `enum map_type_t`. (The `typedef` in your question should have worked; we'd have to see more code to know why it didn't work for you.)

Similar rules apply to `struct` and `union` type declarations.

(The rules are different in C++.)